# Facebook app permissions

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

According to an answer to this question : [Bypass app permissions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97646/bypass-app-permissions), I changed by curiosity  the application permission of Facebook and Messenger for the camera to **always ask**. I'm using CyanogenMod 12.0. Facebook was still able to open the camera without asking me. I then changed it's permission to **Ignore**, but still the camera opened.

Does anyone know why this is working and if there is anything a user can do against it?

Comment: Was the Facebook app restarted between attempts? Or maybe the phone?

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Yes. I tried to restart the app as well as the phone.

Comment: I sadly cannot find the english label for this, but have you a check-box like "Enable Privacy Guard", "Enable Management" or "Enable data protection" on the app details page (right below "Display the notifications")? Is it checked?

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf No there's nothing within the App-Info. But I've enabled the Privacy Guard for Facebook within Options -> Privacy -> Privacy Guard.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you do this to other apps, the camera is blocked properly?

Comment: There are some pretty security concious people who work on CyanogenMod. I suspect we'd get a better answer by looking on the CM forums or mail list.

Comment: Beats me, on my side I get nice popups requiring confirmation. You should definitively ask this question on [android.se] since I think this is merely a CynogenMod issue than a general IT Security one. Be sure to add the version of CyanogeMod you are currently using, and check if you have any other security-related app which may interfere with the common expected behaviour.